# k-permutation of elements in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, permutation

I was looking for a simple method to get a k-permutation of elements in one ArrayList.

I have an arrayList of objects X and I want to get all the possible permutations (order counts) of the elements based on a value k.

So far, I found just Combinations and permutations of all the elements (mostly integer values) but no solutions of k-permutations of Objects in an array list.

Can someone help me?

So far I found this but I have no idea how to adapt to my case:

```
 public static void perm2(String s, int k)
    {
    perm2("", s, k);
    }
    public static void perm2(String prefix, String s, int k)
    {
    int N = prefix.length();

    int M = s.length();

    if(N == k) System.out.println(prefix);
    else
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            perm2(prefix+s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, M), k);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String alphabet = "123";
    int N = alphabet.length();
    int K = 2;
    String elements = alphabet.substring(0, N);
    perm2(elements, K);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look into recursion.  Is this for an assignment?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I think recursion is a good approach to do it. No actually it's not for an assignment. I am working on a fun project.

Comment: Did https://www.google.com/search?q=k-permutations+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab not work? Because you're not reinventing the wheel, you should have been able to find perfectly fine implementations for this already by [searching/researching before posting this question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I spent one hour looking for a solution on google but I have not found any solution with Objects. Just permutations of strings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to generate all permutations of `k` elements from a `List` of length `n`, where `n >= k`.

```
static <E> void permK(List<E> p, int i, int k)
{
  if(i == k)
  {
    System.out.println(p.subList(0, k));
    return;
  }

  for(int j=i; j<p.size(); j++)
  {
    Collections.swap(p, i, j);
    permK(p, i+1, k);    
    Collections.swap(p, i, j);
  }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  permK(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), 0, 3);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 5, 3]
<snip>
[5, 3, 1]
[5, 4, 3]
[5, 4, 2]
[5, 4, 1]
[5, 1, 3]
[5, 1, 4]
[5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to much words. According to the title, you want to get `k-th` ordered permutation of the given array.

Example.

- initial array: `abcde`
- **0th**: `abcde`
- **1st**: `abced`
- **last**: `edcba`
- you need to find `kth` permutation

You have two ways to solve it:

1. Implement lexicogaphic sort manually and iterate it over kth permutation. It takes **O(n)** time;
2. You can use [Factorial number systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), which allows to solve this problem for **O(1)** time.

Comment: Partially. I want also to specify k. So if my initial array is: abcde and I say k = 3 I want the following: 0th: abc 1st abd .... and so on.